# How to position headings directly on top of its own bottom border?

Tags: html, css

How would I go about getting a heading to sit flush on its own bottom border? Is there such a technique as negative padding? Will i have to use underline instead? Or somehow position it to sit on the top border of the element below it? Many thanks.

```css
h1 {
  font: bold 100px/normal Helvetica;
  color: blue;
  border: 5px solid black;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<h1>HEADING TOO HIGH</h1>
```

Comment: padding and line-height.

Comment: padding:0; will take away any padding. looks like a line-height of 0.75 is what you are looking for

Comment: I was trying just padding: 0; without any luck, but with the line-height it worked well. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You could try maybe something like this and play a little bit with the **line-height** property.

```css
h1 {
    line-height: 40px;
    height: 30px;
    padding: 0px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<h1>HEADING TOO HIGH</h1>
```